# Expanding directories in variables with make

Tags: r, bash, variables, path, makefile

I have a makefile (below) for a project where I've been given a folder of "Raw Data" - a set of files from a colleague, and I've made an R script that does an analysis on some of those files. What I want to do with a the makefile then is assign the directory to a variable RAWDIR, and then use that variable in specifying the make dependencies of the R script, and as a command line argument for the script. Usually in the shell, directories with spaces are expanded when using double quotes and curly braces, but I do not know if this is also correct for make files, as with the following makefile I get the message `make: *** No rule to make target`""../Raw', needed by `pulls'.  Stop.` So I do not think my file path assigned to RAWDIR is being expanded properly.

Thanks.

```
RAWDIR="../Raw Data/Fc Project Raw Data"

.PHONY: dirs

pulls: dirs "${RAWDIR}/pm_fc_dnds_cleandata.csv" "${RAWDIR}/fc1_seqs.fasta" "${RAWDIR}/fc2_seqs.fasta" "${RAWDIR}/pm1_seqs.fasta" "${RAWDIR}/pm2_seqs.fasta"
    Rscript Allele_Pulling.R "${RAWDIR}/" "${RAWDIR}/pm_fc_dnds_cleandata.csv"

dirs: 
    mkdir -p -v Pulled_Allelic_Pairs/Unaligned/FC
    mkdir -p -v Pulled_Allelic_Pairs/Unaligned/PM
    mkdir -p -v Pulled_Allelic_Pairs/Unaligned/Both
    mkdir -p -v Pulled_Allelic_Pairs/Unaligned/FC1PM1
    mkdir -p -v Pulled_Allelic_Pairs/Unaligned/FC1PM2
    mkdir -p -v Pulled_Allelic_Pairs/Unaligned/FC2PM1
    mkdir -p -v Pulled_Allelic_Pairs/Unaligned/FC2PM2
    mkdir -p -v Pulled_Allelic_Pairs/Aligned/FC
    mkdir -p -v Pulled_Allelic_Pairs/Aligned/PM
    mkdir -p -v Pulled_Allelic_Pairs/Aligned/Both
    mkdir -p -v Pulled_Allelic_Pairs/Aligned/FC1PM1
    mkdir -p -v Pulled_Allelic_Pairs/Aligned/FC1PM2
    mkdir -p -v Pulled_Allelic_Pairs/Aligned/FC2PM1
    mkdir -p -v Pulled_Allelic_Pairs/Aligned/FC2PM2
```

Comment: I'm not convinced that `make` understands quoted strings or spaces in path names; it comes from an older age when people didn't do that because it hurt when you tried to include spaces in directories.  The error message is consistent with that observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general spaces in pathnames are not well supported by `make`. At least some functions in `GNU make` could handle spaces that are escaped by `\`.

The following should work in your use case:

```
RAWDIR="../Raw\ Data/Fc\ Project\ Raw\ Data"
```